# RealmSwiftのマイグレーションエラーが解決できない

Tags: swift

現在野球のデータベースを自作しています。

RealmSwiftに保存するPitcherとBatterのクラスを両方設定して、現在も製作中です。
その途中、プロパティーの名前を変更したり、変数を追加したりしたところ、下記のようのエラーで立ち、クラッシュするようになってしまいました。

```
fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=0 "Provided schema version 0 is less than last set version 1." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Provided schema version 0 is less than last set version 1.}: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-703.0.18.1/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 54
```

schemaと書いてあるので、マイグレーション関係のエラーだと思い、SwiftDocsを参考にマイグレーション処理を行いました（下記）。

```
    let config = Realm.Configuration(
    schemaVersion: 1,
    migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
        }
})
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
```

念のためRealmに保存してあるデータも

```
let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            realm.deleteAll()
```

を使って初期化しながら開発をしていますが、クラスが複数になったためなのか？は不明ですが、Realmに書き込むボタンを押すとクラッシュします。
どこがいけないのか？お教えいただけますか？
コードはかなり長いため、Uploadはできませが、
どなたか？お解りになる方がいらっしゃればお教え下さい。
お願いいたします。

---

追伸です。
マイグレーション処理をスルーすると下記エラーになります。

```
fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=0 "Migration is required due to the following errors: 
- Property 'tall2' has been added to latest object model." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Migration is required due to the following errors: 
- Property 'tall2' has been added to latest object model.}: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-703.0.18.1/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 54
```

'tall2'というのは選手の身長を示すプロパティーです。
変数の中で一番最後に設定をしました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"Provided schema version 0 is less than last set version 1."
```

上記のエラーメッセージに書いてある通り、最後に設定されたスキーマバージョンは1なので、2以上の値を設定する必要があります。

スキーマ（データ構造）が変わるたびに、古いデータを残すのであればマイグレーションが必要です。その時、スキーマバージョンは必ず前のバージョンより大きい値を指定しなければなりません。

```
"Migration is required due to the following errors:
```

マイグレーション処理を無くしたときに出たという上記のエラーは文字どおり、スキーマ（データ構造）が変わっているのでマイグレーションが必要だというエラーです。マイグレーション処理を書くか、古いファイルを削除してやり直してください。

Comment: 有難うございます。
データを残さなければマイグレーションは不要と考えて良いですか？

Comment: 古いデータを捨てて作り直すのであればもちろんマイグレーションは不要です。